# Does an wall-mounted electric oven require an air gap below, and if so, how large?

Tags: electrical, oven, fire-hazard

I've a wall-mounted electric oven. Or rather I did have before a small, smouldering fire started and neary burnt my house down.
The fire brigade informed me there was no air gap (it was fitted 5 years before I owned the house and sat flush onto chipboard) which caused the issue.
I've found little in any oven installation instructions that details the need for a gap.

So I wondered - is it required? 
Do all ovens ship with 'feet' that enable the oven to sit within a cabinet with the required clearance?

Comment: The manufacturer's documentation should list clearances for the device.

Comment: You'd have thought so wouldn't you. It's vague at best. However the fire brigade stated that it's required. Unfortunately the previous owner/installer didn't deem it necessary. Cue *smouldering fire*.

Comment: The oven I am trying to install does not have an air gap specified in the manual but a 1-1.5 inch gap is built into the design.